# Are there any experimental realizations of semi-Dirac materials?

Tags: condensed-matter, dirac-equation, topological-insulators

My question is there any experimental proof of semi-Dirac dispersion beside optical lattice?

Comment: Can you explain a little what is meant by semi-Dirac?

Comment: Semi-dirac are materials with hybrid type dispersion relation, i.e quadratic in one direction and linear in perpendicular direction.